# Application Loader/Xcode Stuck on 'Verifying Assets with the App Store"

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

While trying to upload my application to App Store Connect, I got stuck at "Verifying Assets with the App Store" for 4-5 hours. My network is fine, running at 50-60 upstream, and well over 100 downstream.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To fix this issue, I opened the Application Loader, opened the Preferences (`⌘ + ,`) and navigated to the 'Advanced' tab.

**Disable the Signiant and Aspera Transfer Protocols** but leave DAV on.
[image: Disable transfer protocols]

Comment: it keeps on uploading app again & again. Starts from 0 to 100% and then starts again. no stopping/finishing