# Xcode 10 app upload stuck on "negotiating connection..."

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, release, application-loader

I'm trying to release a new application using Cordova. I confirmed certificates or provisioning things already. And I do follow the process "Product" -> "Archive"-> "Validation" and it succeeded with no error messages. Finally I clicked "Distribution" but it is stuck on "Negotiating connection..." I waited for several hours but nothing changed.

I tried Application Loader and Xcode 10.1 but I am stuck on both.

(I also sent this question to Apple, and I am waiting for a response.)

Comment: I have a same problem.

Comment: I tried downgrading from 10.1 to 10.0, but it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Loader/Xcode Stuck on 'Verifying Assets with the App Store"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770972/application-loader-xcode-stuck-on-verifying-assets-with-the-app-store)

Comment: No, not the same issue as getting stuck at "Verifying Assets with the App Store"

Comment: Did you fix the issue? Having the same problem

Comment: @Jakob Yes, I solved this problem. please see my answer below.

Comment: Just be calm and wait this will automatically resolved, and app will be automatically uploaded to appstore by sure.
This is not issue if there is some kind of network error occur than this message is shown, but this will auto resolved.
I have uploaded recently 3 app.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem from answer addressed in below link.

[application loader xcode stuck on verifying assets with the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770972/application-loader-xcode-stuck-on-verifying-assets-with-the-app-store)

OR Use Application Loader

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me

Comment: In my case it works using `Application Loader` and disabling `Signiant` and `Aspera` protocols

Comment: it keeps on uploading app again & again. Starts from 0 to 100% and then starts again. no stopping/finishing

Comment: @AnthoPak thanks, disabling those protocols fixes it for me, too (as of today, using Application Loader from Xcode 10.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

Wait on the same screen it will revoke automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case tethering to an iPhone solved it. So I suggest that you try to change the network.